# Why new Xcode 9.0 can't find Embedded Binaries?

Tags: xcode

Why new Xcode 9.0 can't find Embedded Binaries?
I USE the xcode 9, I wanner add Embedded Binaries file. but, in xcode, I can't find embedded binaries? how?

Comment: Xcode 9 is not new. Xcode 10.1 is the latest.